# Examples or Tools for SQL server database deployment automation

Tags: sql-server, automation, sql-server-data-tools, sql-scripts, database-deployment

Off late I am searching the internet for an automated solution for SQL server database deployments primarily to avoid manual steps of maintaining and deploying sql scripts for deployments.

My situation is peculiar. It does not require me to maintain a whole database but 'only' customizations to the databases. Let me elaborate.

There are atleast 3 to 4 different SQL server databases that pertain to different 3rd party applications. I am tasked with writing integration between these systems(essentially between these many different databases in reality).

While considering to use SSDT(Sql server data tools) it advocates me to create a database project so I am not sure if it will exactly fit my need to maintain 'only' a subset of a database(I am assuming SSDT would want me to start with importing the entire database and then maintain it as I need.. which i do not want to do it this way).

If this can be achieved with SSDT, I am better off iwth that and appreciate if someone can point me in that direction to some how-tos. Otherwise, are there any other options or customized solutions that can help.?

I recently spent lot of time reading through this [Simpletalk Article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/automating-sql-server-database-deployments-a-worked-example/?utm_source=simpletalk&utm_medium=weblink&utm_content=scriptingdetails&utm_campaign=simpletalk), but it doesn't seem to be a completely free solution. For instance, it uses an encrypted(.vbe) vb script which seems to be doing most of the tasks but the author(for some reason!) did not provide the source code for the vb script which stops me from considering..

I am not sure if I can build on top of this without having to worry about the vb script source code not available..

Overall, I am looking for a customized solution or a tool that can help me maintain changes to databases and automate deployment of my changes while adding mechanisms to maintain database versions.. Any help is much appreciated!!

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Found dbdeploy to be the tool that I can use for my task.

It has several falvors and different authorings though.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/dbdeploy/

---

DbDeploy.Net for use with .Net/SQL server environments.

adapted from http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbdeploy-net/ ...

... https://github.com/rakker91/dbdeploy.net

- available as [Nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/DbDeployNet2/)

---

From another author: https://github.com/brunomlopes/dbdeploy.net